# SPARQL Query OWL Wine Ontology

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology

Im trying to do a SPARQL query in the Wine ontology and by a given wine name find all its properties (hasMaker, locatedIn, hasBody etc).

Is this possible at all? I cant really figure out how to form the query.

Wine ontology: www.w3.org/TR/owl-guide/wine.rdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly it is quite easy.

Here is an example on how to do it (without PREFIXES). Here I presume that you have the wine URI.

```
select distinct ?p where {
    vin:MountadamChardonnay ?p ?a .
}
```

Here you return all properties that your wine has.

If you do not have the wine URI, you can add a check for label or name of the wine before fetching rest of the properties. Below is an example. (If there is another name property just change it with rdfs:label, rdf:id etc). This example is more relevant if you had any other idetifier inside each wine resource.

```
select distinct ?p where {
    ?wine rdfs:label <wine name> .
    ?wine ?p ?a .
}
```

Comment: is this possible when the wine name is a rdf:id? (a node instead of a property)

Comment: @andweas I took a look at your ontology. It should work if the ID is unique. I have not checked it all so I don't know if rdf:id's are uniwue in your ontology, but if rdf:id is used correctly each rdf:id should be unique. I have changed my answer to use rdf:id instead of rdfs:label

Comment: @andweas Ok. Took a closer look at the wine ontology. With rdf:id you add the name to the wine uri. This means that you can use the SPARQL query in example one to do your test. You only need to ask for the wine with the base URI (http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/PR-owl-guide-20031209/wine#) + the name(id) of the wine.

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work now. I for some reason have a really hard time grasping sparql queries.

Comment: @andweas One thing to note is that RDF/XML is one of the least human-readable syntaxes for RDF.  RDF itself doesn't have any notion of rdf:resource or rdf:id;  those are just used in the XML serialization of RDF.  Look at the [Turtle/N3 serialization of the wine ontology](http://rdf-translator.appspot.com/convert/xml/n3/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FTR%2Fowl-guide%2Fwine.rdf);  it's much more like the SPARQL syntax.  The important thing to realize is that RDF is a *graph*-based data representation, and SPARQL is for writing *graph*-based patterns.